# Ios 7 crash -Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES

Tags: iphone, ios7

in    supportedInterfaceOrientations method application crashing i have tried more orientation but app crashing for the same

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate

```
{
    return NO;

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    //return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

// Old Method
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

{

 if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))

{
        return NO;

}

else

{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "Deployment info" section in your project settings